# Remove duplicates pairwise in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, duplicates, filtering

I have multiple lists of integers.

```
val firstList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
val secondList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8)
val thirdList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 6, 9)
```

...

I need to remove duplicates only among the other lists, and not within a list itself.

The result should be:

```
[1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,9]
```

What is the best approach to do so in Kotlin?

Comment: I'm guessing that `arrayListOf(1, 6, 9)` should be named `thirdList`?

Comment: This is quite underspecified. Is it an accident that the lists are ordered, or is it expected? Should the result be sorted too? What happens if there is a 10 in the first list? Should it be before or after the 9 in the result? How do you choose the number of occurrences of a number in the result? Should it appear as many times as it appears in the list it appears the most times in? Or should it appear as many times as it appears in the first list it appears in?

Answer (score 2):

We can filter the additional lists with a `.filter` and `.contains`, then add the result to the `firstList`. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it should work.

```
val firstList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
val secondList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8)
val thirdList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(1, 6, 9)
    
firstList += secondList.filterNot { firstList.contains(it) }
firstList += thirdList.filterNot { firstList.contains(it) }
    
firstList.sort() //not sure if you want the firstList to be sorted or not
```

You could also make it an extension function, so then it is easier to call.

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.addOtherNoDuplicates(vararg others: Iterable<T>){
    others.forEach {other ->
        this += other.filterNot { this.contains(it) }
    }
}
```

Then the call would just be:

```
firstList.addOtherNoDuplicates(secondList, thirdList) //add as many as you want
firstList.sort()
```

If you only want to use it for ArrayList, then you can replace the `MutableCollection<T>` with `ArrayList<T>` and use the `sort()` directly in the function itself.

Comment: You could reduce the code block in _addOtherNoDuplicates_ to _others.forEach { this += it.filterNot(this::contains) }_.

Comment: Maybe nice to mention: If it's not desired to change the first list just create an empty one first, for example `val result: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()` and then do `result.addOtherNoDuplicates(firstList, secondList, thirdList)`

Answer (score 2):

If these are very long lists, you can use a MutableSet on the side to efficiently avoid adding the unwanted values.

```
val input = listOf(firstList, secondList, thirdList)
val allValues = mutableSetOf<Int>()
val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
for (list in input) {
    val newValues = list.filterNot { it in allValues }
    result.addAll(newValues)
    allValues.addAll(newValues)
}

println(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't work entirely correct though. If secondList has four 1s for example I think OP would want to have four in the result. This answer gives three 1s in the result because firstList has three of them

Comment: I interpreted it as going in order. 1 first appears in the first list, so in the result it should appear the number of times it appears in the first list.  Sounds like you are interpreting it as a number should appear as many times as it appears in the list it appears the most times in. The requirements are a bit ambiguous.

Comment: yeah, that's how I interpreted it. I'm not sure which interpretation is right